# PCRE regex - how to capture first match from lines above the pattern?

Tags: regex, pcre

I have following text in a file:

```
mysql_databases:
  potato_mychat1:
    - potato_mychat1
  potato_phpb1:
    - potato_phpb1
    - potato_smf1
  potato_phpb2:
    - potato_phpb2
  p_phpb282:
    - potato_phpb282
  potato_registry:
    - potato_registryadmi
  potato_smf1:
    - potato_smf1
  potato_smf2:
    - potato_smf2
  potato_wp82:
   - potato_wp82
```

The pattern would be `- potato_smf1`.

Te first string ending with `:` above each match should be marked - so in this case `potato_phpb1:` and `potato_smf1:`.

I have tried many variations of positive lookbehind: `(?<= - potato_smf)*:` but can't get it right no matter what, I will appreciate any hints.

Comment: That sort of works, thank you, however, it's marking just the first match from the bottom, it doesn't mark the `potato_phpb1`

Comment: If my answer does not help you solve the issue, please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can rely on indentation, you can use

```
(?m)^\h{2}\S.*(?=(?:\R\h{4}.*)*?\R\h{4}- potato_smf1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XkeQ6j/1)

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `\h{2}` - two horizontal whitespaces
- `\S.*` - a non-whitespace and then any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(?=(?:\R\h{4}.*)*?\R\h{4}- potato_smf1)` - a positive lookahead that requires, immediately on the right,

  - `(?:\R\h{4}.*)*?` - zero or more, but as few as possible, repetitions of a line break, four horizontal whitespaces and then zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\R` - a line break
  - `\h{4}` - four horizontal whitespaces
  - `- potato_smf1` - a literal text.